# SSIS - Export image datatype column to a flat file

Tags: sql, ssis, binary, bcp

I would like to export a table with image data-type column to a flat file using SSIS package and back.

Is this possible or should I use another approach?

By the way, the BCP utility do the job but I prefer working with SSIS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create SSIS package and try to add Data Flow Task with Data Source and Flat File Destination. When you create Flat File Destination component, you create Flat File Connection. Here you can choose appropriate data types for each column at Advanced tab. I saw image[DT_IMAGE] type here. You could try it.